# JMS JMSCC3032 exception

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, jms-topic

I use IBM MQ. I upgraded the `com.ibm.mq` jar in my application from 7.5 to 9.1.1.0 as:

```xml
<groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
<artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId> 
<version>9.1.1.0</version>
```

My consumer that is receiving messages from topic started to get error `JMSCC0111`.

As I read this is new behavior in the JMS libraries above version 8.0 where by default a JMS ID can not be reused.
As a solution I set clientId on connection as below. I'm getting connection from `ConnectionFactory`.

```java
public Connection getConnectionWithUuid() throws JMSException {
    Connection connection = connFactory.createConnection();
    String uid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    connection.setClientID(uid);
    connection.start();
    return connection;
}
```

Now I started to get exception:

```
JMSCC3032: Resetting the client ID is not allowed.
```

```java
Connection jmsConnection = null;
Session jmsSession = null;
MessageConsumer consumer = null;
MessageProducer producer = null;
try {
    jmsConnection = QueueManager.getInstance().getConnectionWithUuid();
    jmsSession = jmsConnection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Destination responseTopic = QueueManager.getInstance()
            .getDestination(this.parameters.getResponseTopicName());
    Destination outGoingQueue = QueueManager.getInstance()
            .getDestination(this.parameters.getOutGoingQueueName());
    consumer = jmsSession.createConsumer(responseTopic);
    producer = jmsSession.createProducer(outGoingQueue);
    TextMessage requestMessage = jmsSession.createTextMessage(request);
    requestMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(parameters.getSessionId());
    producer.send(requestMessage);
    logMessage("OutGoing Message:\n", requestMessage);
    String response = null;
    long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (response == null && System.currentTimeMillis() - begin < protocolTimeoutSecs * 1000) {
        Message responseMessage = consumer.receive(protocolTimeoutSecs * 1000);
```

On the last line (`consumer.receive`) it throws `JMSCC3032`.

Comment: What's the point of setting a random client ID in the first place? Generally speaking each application would have its own client ID that would be used consistently. The client ID is designed to uniquely and deterministically identify a particular connection. Generating a unique ID every time defeats this purpose.

Comment: Yes I use IBM MQ.with uppgrade,I mean I uppgraded version of com.ibm.mq jar version from 7.5 to 9.1.1.0 as
                      
 <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
 <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
 <version>9.1.1.0</version>

Comment: Have you tried simply *not* setting the client ID? It doesn't appear that your application needs to set it at all.

Comment: To be clear, the JMS specification has _always_ disallowed multiple connections using the same client ID.

Comment: Yes,It was working without setting clientId,after jar uppgrade it started to get Exception JMSCC0111,I searched a bit and setting clientId  seemed as solution but it didnt work